# I want to use objective C code in swift. Once I add a bridging header I start getting errors for all primitive data types

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

I have a model

```
@interface Section : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sectionId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;

+(instancetype)createObject:(NSDictionary *)sectionInfo;    
@end
```

My bridging header looks like this

```
// MyProj-Bridging-Header.h    

#ifndef MyProj_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyProj_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Section.h"

#endif /* MyProj_Bridging_Header_h */
```

My Swift controller looks like this

```
@objc class SampleSwiftVC : UIViewController {
    var supportedSectionInfo: Section?
}
```

I start getting compile time errors like

```
/*PathToProject*/Section.h:17:39: error: expected a type
+(instancetype)createObject:(NSDictionary *)sectionInfo;
                                  ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/*PathToProject*/MyProj-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I went over to the build settings and found that the header file reference is set for the `Objective-C Bridging header` key
[image]

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: @PiyushPatel, thank you for the link but this does not seem to help my cause.

Comment: @iosCurator For example try to replace instancetype with id in createObject method signature.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @Roman Podymov, but did not help. I am still getting unknown type for NSString.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was that the ObjectiveC model was inherited from the NSObject.h. This was the actual problem because the Foundation class was not imported. Adding

`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

before

`@interface Section : NSObject`

solved the issue